# Eliminating Redundant NULL checks in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

```
List<OfferDTO> offers = dbContext.Offer.Where(x => x.IsDeleted)
    .OrderBy(i => i.OfferID)
    .Skip(start).Take((length))
    .Select(y => new OfferDTO
    {
        OfferStageValue = y.OfferStage.Value ?? null,
        PropertyAddressLine1 = (y.PropertyAuction.Property != null && y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address != null) ? y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address.AddressLine1 : string.Empty,
        PropertyAddressLine2 = (y.PropertyAuction.Property != null && y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address != null) ? y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address.AddressLine2 : string.Empty,
        PropertyCity = (y.PropertyAuction.Property != null && y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address != null) ? y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address.City : string.Empty,
        PropertyZip = (y.PropertyAuction.Property != null && y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address != null) ? y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address.PostalCode : string.Empty,            
    })
    .ToList();
```

In the above example, I am casting directly to an object with a select statement.

Certain properties need to be checked for a `null` value before their values are used in the new object.

However, as you see, different properties check the same value for `null` over and over again. Specifically here, you see:

`(y.PropertyAuction.Property != null && y.PropertyAuction.Property.Address != null)`

is checked a few times in a row.

In the ensuing SQL, you are seeing that the query is checking for `null` each time:

```
CASE WHEN (([Extent12].[PropertyID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent13].[AddressID] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent14].[AddressLine1] ELSE @p__linq__1 END AS [C5], 
CASE WHEN (([Extent12].[PropertyID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent15].[AddressID] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent16].[AddressLine2] ELSE @p__linq__2 END AS [C6], 
CASE WHEN (([Extent12].[PropertyID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent17].[AddressID] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent18].[City] ELSE @p__linq__3 END AS [C7]
```

Is there a way to check once and carry that over, or is this the best way to safely use these values?

**NOTE**

`y` is the base table

`PropertyAuction`,
`Property`, and
`Address` are all separate tables as well and may not contain data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a bit more elegant in the LINQ itself by switching to Query syntax, and using the `let` keyword, but I think you're going to find your generated SQL is (has to be) pretty similar:

```
var offers = (from o in dbContext.Offers
              where o.IsDeleted
              let p = o.PropertyAuction.Property
              let a = p != null ? p.Address : null
              orderby o.OfferID
              select new OfferDTO
    {
        OfferStageValue = o.OfferStage.Value,
        PropertyAddressLine1 = a != null ? a.AddressLine1 : string.Empty,
        PropertyAddressLine2 = a != null ? a.AddressLine2 : string.Empty,
        PropertyCity = a != null ? a.City : string.Empty,
        PropertyZip = a != null ? a.PostalCode : string.Empty,
    })
    .Skip(start).Take(length)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Just got a chance to put the full model into the compiler and check the SQL - as expected, the generated SQL is identical to the SQL generated from your original query; (i.e., even though extracted into a single check in the LINQ, the generated SQL inlines these checks four times, resulting in identical SQL code).

If your primary goal was cleaner LINQ code, at least this answer accomplishes that.